# Is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion

This question: [What are the name and origin of the woodworking style used for this wooden cabinet with rounded features?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/help-identify-a-wooden-cabinet) is getting downvotes and comments as off topic. The question is for help in identifying a historic style, not wood types or opinions.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I was just about to come here to ask the same question. I'd assumed identifying antique furniture was off topic, similar to how identifying species of wood is off topic. But perhaps not! Thanks for opening this question.

Answer (score 9):

As currently written, the question is asking for the origin and history of this particular piece, so it wouldn't be a good fit for this site for various reasons, including the following:

- It would likely require significant back-and-forth discussion
- The answer is not likely to be very useful to other visitors of the site
- It may be incredibly difficult to identify just from photos, without being able to handle it and examine it closely, similar to wood identification questions

If the question were reworded to ask for identification of the general woodworking style, that seems like it may be in-scope, particularly if the features can be described in the title of the question.